# "add/show X more comments" - weird lag glitch

Tags: support, comments

Just recently I've been noticing this.

On SO, sometimes when I click "add/show X more comments", the add comment edit box is shown immediately, but the additional comments aren't shown for several seconds. There's no indication that the browser is accessing the site during this time.

Maybe it's my browser/environment (IE 8 on Windows 7 Enterprise, on a LAN with a proxy on the other side of the country (USA)). I can't remember noticing it on Chrome but I haven't accessed SO from home much lately.

It doesn't happen most of the time and I can't reproduce it at will. It's just weird.

Comment: Note that the additional comments have to be retrieved from the servers.  Everything isn't just downloaded at the start, hidden then shown when clicked.  The lag you're seeing is probably due to normal connection lag.

Comment: @Jeff, that makes sense, as internet access here can be laggy; it just feels weird when the browser shows no sign of activity at all during that time.

Comment: Most of the time it's virtually instantaneous, so I actually thought it maust have downloaded the rest of the comments already.

Answer (score 3):

This has always been this way; on fast connections, it's hardly noticable, but Jeff Mercado's comment is correct, the rest of the comments is retrieved from the server. So when this takes seconds, I assume the intertubes are clogged somewhere between you and our servers. FWIW, I hardly ever see an extended delay, and I live even further away than you.

Comment: I suspect the delay may even be in my work WAN, since most of the infrastructure is in Illinois while I'm in Oregon.